LWC hover card position issue
Hey I am developing a LWC component where it shows all the accounts when I hover on the account the hover-card will be shown with related opportunities , the functionality is working fine but i am facing issues with the placement of the popover for some records it's showing correctly , for some records the hover-card is on very top
<template>
    <template if:true={isLoading}>
        <!-- <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small" class="spinner"></lightning-spinner> -->
    </template>
    <template if:false={isLoading}>
        <!-- <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small"></lightning-spinner> -->
        <div class="account_container">
            <template for:each={accountData} for:item="accountsInfo">
                <div class="sub_card" key={accountsInfo.Id}>
                    <a href="https://login.salesforce.com" data-id={accountsInfo.Id} target="_blank"
                        onmouseover={handleMouseOver} onblur={handleMouseOut}>{accountsInfo.Name}</a>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card slds-card_boundary hover-card" style={hoverCardStyle}>
            <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
                <div class="slds-text-title slds-truncate">Opportunities</div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <template for:each={currentSelectedOpportunities} for:item="opportunity">
                    <div key={opportunity.Id} class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small slds-m-bottom_small slds-border_bottom">
                        <p class="slds-text-title slds-truncate">
                            <a href="https://login.salesforce.com" class="slds-text-link"
                                target="_blank">
                                {opportunity.Name}
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        
                        <p>Amount: ${opportunity.Amount}</p>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>

    </template>
</template>

import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getAccountsInfo from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountsInfo.getAccountsInfo';
export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
    @track isLoading = true;
    @track accountData;
    @track currentAccountOpportunities;


    connectedCallback() {
        getAccountsInfo().then((results) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
            this.accountData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }).finally(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        })
    }
    hoverCardStyle = 'display: none;'; // Default style for the hover card

    handleMouseOver(event) {
        const accountId = event.target.dataset.id;
        const selectedAccount = this.accountData.find(account => account.Id === accountId);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedAccount));
        if (selectedAccount) {
            if(selectedAccount.Opportunities===undefined){
                 this.hoverCardStyle = 'display: none;';
                this.currentAccountOpportunities=[];
            }
            this.currentSelectedOpportunities = [...selectedAccount.Opportunities] || null;
            this.currentSelectedOpportunities = selectedAccount.Opportunities ? [...selectedAccount.Opportunities] : [];
            console.log('SelectedOpportunities',JSON.stringify(this.currentAccountOpportunities));
            this.updateHoverCardPosition(event);
        }
    }

    handleMouseOut() {
        this.currentSelectedOpportunities = [];
        this.hoverCardStyle = 'display: none;'; // Hide hover card when mouse is out
    }

    updateHoverCardPosition(event) {
        // this.hoverCardStyle = `display: block; left: ${event.pageX + 10}px; : right${event.pageY + 10}px;`;
        this.hoverCardStyle = `display: block; left: ${event.pageX + 10}px; right: ${event.pageY + 10}px;`;

    }
}

#css stylings
.account_container{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* position: relative;  */
}
.sub_card{
    text-align: center;
    margin: .2rem;
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    padding: .5rem;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    position: relative;
}


.hover-card {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f4f6f9;
    border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* padding: 1rem; */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}


I want it exactly on the top of the accountname link

You don't need any JavaScript to make this happen. All you need is a bit of CSS.
<div class="account" for:each={accounts} for:item="account" key={account.Id}>
{!account.Name}
  <div class="opportunityList">
    <div class="opportunity" for:each={account.Opportunities} for:item="opportunity" key={opportuntity.Id}>
      {opportunity.Name}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

From there, you just need the appropriate CSS, which looks like this:
.account {
 position: relative;
}
.account .opportunityList {
  display: none;
}
.account:hover .opportunityList {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

This is not a complete example, but is meant to illustrate that you can do this without any use of JavaScript, which performs much better in the long run.
